# Do I use fadeIn() wrong?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Looking at [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/) I get the impression that I just have to add `.fadeIn("slow")` to an element like so

```
$('#template').tmpl(data).prependTo('#content').fadeIn("slow");
```

but it appears instantaneously and doesn't even give an error.

It can be seen here

http://jsfiddle.net/HYLYq/8/

```js
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('form').live('submit', function(){
      var aform = $(this).serializeArray();  
      var data = {};
      var i = aform.length; 
      while(i--) {
          data[aform [i].name] = aform [i].value;
      } 
      $('#template').tmpl(data).prependTo('#content').fadeIn("slow");
      return false;      
  });
});
```

```html
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.datepicker.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery.tmpl() -->
    <script src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery.templates/beta1/jquery.tmpl.min.js"></script>

    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/external/jquery.bgiframe-2.1.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.core.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.widget.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.mouse.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.button.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.draggable.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.position.js"></script>
    <script src="http://jqueryui.com/ui/jquery.ui.dialog.js"></script>

    <!-- template that will be used for inserting a form live when the okay bottom have been pressed and succeeded -->
    <script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="template">
    ${title} ${owner}
      </script>

      
    <form id="create_form" name="create_form" action="" method="post">
      <input  type="text" name="title" id="title" value="test1" />
      <input  type="text" name="owner" id="owner" value="test2" /><br class="new"/>
          <button class="n" type="submit">Create</button>
    </form>
      
    <div id="content"> </div>
```

Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: If you were interested in why your statement doesn't work as it currently is, even when you insert hide - it's because it's currently targeting the wrong element :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to `.hide()` it before appending it to the DOM.

```
$('#template').tmpl(data).hide().prependTo('#content').fadeIn("slow");
```

Alternatively, you could put `style="display:none;"` in the HTML of your template and then you wouldn't need `.hide()`.

**EDIT:** Also, your template is only text.  So, .hide() will not work unless you wrap it in something first.  A `<span>` or `<div>` should work just fine.

Answer (score 1):

Hide the element first, then only fadein effect will be visible

```
$(document).ready(function(){    
  $('form').live('submit', function(){
      var aform = $(this).serializeArray();  
      var data = {};
      var i = aform.length;
      while(i--) {
          data[aform [i].name] = aform [i].value;
      }
      $('#template').tmpl(data).prependTo('#content');
      $("#content").hide();
      $("#content").fadeIn("slow");
      return false;      
  });
});
```