# How to make fadein & fadeout in Javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to make fadein and fadeout effects as jQuery but by using javascript itself (vanilla JavaScript).

**Please write simplest way to do that**

Comment: Duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6187495/do-i-use-fadein-wrong

Comment: Pedantic side-note: People usually use the term `vanilla JavaScript` when referring to JavaScript without the use of frameworks, because jQuery **is** JavaScript.

Comment: @Erik: That is not _at all_ a duplicate.

Comment: @Erik - i want javascript not jquery

Comment: @Lion: jQuery **is** Javascript.  There's nothing wrong with using it.

Comment: do not forget to mark answer as correct if you get the info you want

Comment: @LionKing what's the best answer?

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use jQuery.

If you don't want to use jQuery, you'll need to use `setInterval` to run a function that changes the `style.opacity` and `filter` (for IE<9) of an element.